# SP2010: How to ensure that JPG Picture from asset library is not cached by browser when embedded in Wiki page?

Tags: 2010

I have the following two libraries on my site:

- Wiki Page Library called "Site Pages"
- Assets Library called "Assets"

When I upload the JPG to the asset library and add the JPG to the wiki page using the "Insert Picture" functionality, the picture is displayed properly the first time. But when I update the JPG afterwards within the asset library, the browser keeps showing the cached version of the JPG file.

How can I force the browser to always retrieve the latest picture from the asset library? Can I control the cache settings of the assets in an asset library?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to put some random number in Query String of the URL of image like:

`<img src='/Assets/myPicture?v=1414224214' />`

You might need to inject some JavaScript to generate the image URL with random number. Once the browser finds new query string it will reload the image.

Comment: That might work but is not very cool from a usability perspective as changing the query string manually is cumbersome in the WYSIWYG editor. Adding JavaScript is even worse...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to some useful info from Stack overflow, it isn't SharePoint specific but may help you out?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/

Or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/

Or if this is just your browser/client problem you can hit `CTRL + F5` to force refresh on the page. If users haven't seen the original image they will see the new one, but this is really a browser cache problem and not a SharePoint problem.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if the header of the HTTP get reply would contain the cache control fields for all asset library artifact requests.